# browser adding comma and domain name on links with partial url

Tags: python, nginx

On my python 3, flask based website recently upgraded from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. i have noticed strange thing when i run my site using gunicorn behind nginx (1.12.2) and click on links such as blog which are defined in href tag just as "/blog" once i click on them i am redirected to domain.com,domain.com/blog? If i hover over link i see it proper link as domain.com/blog. If i start site locally without gunicorn and nginx it works properly. There is no change in code just modules upgraded along with os version and nginx. Btw i am running this using circus proc manager.

Just need pointers as what could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case this was problem with Nginx.
When nginx config was like this:

```
       location / {
       include proxy_params;
       proxy_set_header   Host                 $host;
       proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7001;
              }
```

I have got :

```
Location : https://domain.test,domain.test
```

Two Urls with comma separated.
And problem was in this line in /etc/nginx/proxy_params

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

I commented it and  site works well.
So, correct config is :

```
           location / {
       # include proxy_params;  -- remove this line
       proxy_set_header   Host                 $host;
       proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7001;
              }
```

Comment: `include proxy_params;` includes the 3 lines below it. You can see yourself using `sudo cat /etc/nginx/proxy_params` (also it uses $http_host, not $host)

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with your Nginx settings rather than gunicorn as I encountered the same problem yesterday. I'm just a beginner on this but I guess gunicorn somehow react to "X-Forwarded-For" in header in an unexpected way.

My solution was: remove the first line in your conf file under sites-enabled(-available), and delete the second as well if it doesn't work.

```
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
```